# How am I able to connect to internet using my mobile phone?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, modem, mobile-phone

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question.

I connect myself to internet using a `ADSL` modem. The `CAT-5` cable is connected both sides to `RJ-45` port ,one on my laptop and the other on the modem.

But now days we can connect our laptop to internet using a mobile phone.For example in Android sets,there is a feature called *USB Tethering* that lets you connect to internet. You just have to connect one side of the USB cable to laptop and inject the other side to the phone (then check the tethering feature) and we are connected to the internet.
Android is relatively a new thing.Before Android I used to connect to internet via bluetooth using my nokia phone.Just install the Nokia PC suite , configure it and you are easily connected to the internet.

My question is : How am I able to connect to internet using the examples I gave above. The one of android and the other of bluetooth? Is it that the mobile phone acts as a modem? More specifically a wireless modem!

ADSL modems are connected to the splitters , which in turn is connected to the wire from *Telephone exchange* or *CO*. But here I see nothing.

Please explain how this entire thing works.I can tether be it Linux or windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is : How am I able to connect to internet using the examples I gave above. The one of android and the other of bluetooth. ? Is it that the mobile phone acts as a modem ? More specifically a wireless modem !

Your phone contains a cellular modem. Tethering essentially creates a wired/wireless connection from your computer to the cellphone, creating an Internet connection routed via the cellphone's modem

Comment: When you enable USB tethering, the Android phone exposes itself as a network interface (emulated of course). It also has router and NAT software running so your computer can share your phones mobile internet connection. This is similar to enabling internet connection sharing on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can share and there are apps also but for that u need rooted android device….
Try this site, it may help. http://mobotalks.com/android/how-to-use-pc-internet-on-android-phone-via-usb-cable-ultimate-guide/